# pivot object over two different axes by pulling on its edges

Tags: animation

I'll do my best to explain this... I need to pivot a plane along its X and Y axes by raising and lowering its corners (two at a time).

In the images below, the cylinders should be raised and lowered as indicated by the arrows and cause the plane to tilt accordingly.
[image: tilt along X axis]
[image: tilt along Y axis]

In the end, I just want to be animating the cylinders - they should 'drag' the plane along resulting in the tilt motions... Also, moving all cylinders up or down should raise or lower the plane.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to rotate the plane, which in turn makes the cylinders go up and down, you can do it this way. (I'm using blender 2.79)

1. Select a cylinder, then the Plane.
2. Go to Edit mode
3. Select one vertex of the nearest corner to that cylinder, then go to Mesh/Vertices/Make vertex parent, and click on the "confirm" dialogue box that pops up.
4. Come back into Object mode and repeat 1 - 3 for the other 3 corners.
5. Give each cylinder a Limit Location Constraint.  Copy each cylinders current X and Y position and paste them into the first two fields of Minimum and Maximum values in the constraint.  That is, limit the location to exactly where they are on the X and Y axes but leave them free to move on the Z axis.
6. Rotate the plane on the X or Y axis and the cylinders will move (vertically only) accordingly.
   [image]

Comment: Thanks! I finally got around to trying this out. That worked!

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is your cylinders need armatures with bone constraints for certain axes (either  rotation or location bone constraints)

Comment: yes but what about the plane?

Comment: Connect each object to its own bone, and then play around with bone constraints for each. Link all the cylinder bones to the plane bone too.

Comment: could you please propose a detailed answer?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to drive it from the motion of the plane-- you can drive it from the cylinders.  Here's how.  But first....

Let's talk about how your system isn't fully defined.  First, a plane is defined from the position of 3 points on a plane, not 4-- so we can't meet any arbitrary position of the 4 cylinders.  We can make it work by raising one set of pillars, and we can make it work by raising a perpendicular set of pillars, but we cannot adjust the height of both sets and still get a plane out of it-- the four pillars would be non-planar!

There's another issue here too, which is that if you raise the pillars, the distance between them increases.  So if your plane doesn't stretch, it won't be attached to the pillars any longer.

So with that in mind, here's how to drive it from the pillars-- again, remembering that we can raise one set, or the other set, but not both.

[image]

Our deforming bones: defPlane, defNW, defSW, defSE, defNE (our four pillars.)  We also have a root, two tracking bones, and two control bones.

We'll start by having our control bones affect our pillars.  NE and SE get a copy location constraint (local to local, with offset) targeting ctrlE, so if we raise E, those go up.  NE and NW get copy location targeting ctrlN.  Since NE is in both groups, it has two constraints, which is why we need the offset.  (Mostly this could be done with parenting, but the one that needs double "parents" means we need at least one constraint, so I just handled all of the relationships in the same way, with copy location constraints.)

TrackX and TrackZ need to get a proper position exactly halfway between their appropriate pillars.  In this case, I did that with an armature constraint (0.5 weight to both pillars).  defPlane needs to get a location in the exact middle of all four pillars, so I started with an armature constraint for it as well, with all four bones in the constraint at weight 0.25.  (There are a lot of other ways you can get this position.  Anything is fine.  This is just what I did.  Note that any bones acquiring position from an armature constraint should be root level-- they're already acquiring the root-bone transform from their constraint targets.)

Now we need to adjust the rotation of the plane.  We'll do this with a pair of locked track constraints.  We'll lock Z and track TrackX in X (duh.)  And we'll lock X and track TrackZ in Z.  For any motion of *one* control, one of these tracking bones will already be exactly where defPlane is pointing anyways, so one of them is redundant, and order doesn't matter.  And we've already established above that manipulating both controls is right out anyways-- we'll no longer have a plane if we do that.